# Sample() returns (0, 0, 0) for normal map 90% of frames

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl, fragment-shader

I'm having some trouble reading the values from my Normal map in my lighting fragment shader.

The relevant part of the shader code is as follows:

```
Texture2D NormalGB : register(t0);
Texture2D DiffuseGB : register(t1);
Texture2D SpecularGB : register(t2);
Texture2D PositionGB : register(t3);

SamplerState NormalSampler : register(s0);

void GetGBValues(
    in int2 screenPosition,
    out float3 normal,
    out float3 diffuseAlbedo,
    out float3 specularAlbedo,
    out float specularPower,
    out float3 position)
{

    int3 screenPos3 = int3(screenPosition, 0);
    normal = normalize(NormalGB.Sample(NormalSampler, screenPosition).xyz); // HERE
    diffuseAlbedo = DiffuseGB.Load(screenPos3).xyz;
    float4 specularValues = SpecularGB.Load(screenPos3);
    specularAlbedo = specularValues.xyz;
    specularPower = specularValues.w * 50.0f;
    position = PositionGB.Load(screenPos3).xyz;
}
```

However, in 9 frames out of 10, normal is set to `{0. 0, 0}`. I've tried the code under the reference driver too, and get the same issue.

What's really weird is that if I change the line marked `// HERE` to a simple `.Load` call, the code works perfectly (except the obvious fact that I get no interpolation of normals). The sampler that is bound at time of the draw call (according to the graphics debugger) is:

```
D3D11 Sampler State (obj:18)
AddressU D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP 
AddressV D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP 
AddressW D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP 
BorderColor (0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f) 
ComparisonFunc D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER 
Filter D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC 
MaxAnisotropy 4 
MaxLOD 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000f 
MinLOD 0.000f 
MipLODBias 0.000f 

Device obj:3
```

And finally, the normal-map (rendered to a texture by the previous pass):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screenPosition` is not at the right scale for texture coordinate lookup.  `Texture2D::Sample` expects texture coordinates (`0..1`) while `Texture2D::Load` expects *texel* coordinates (`0..[Width or Height]-1`).  So you're probably sampling way off the edge of the texture and either hitting the border color, or clamping to the edge which happens to be black.

As a temporary solution, you can simply scale `screenPosition` by some fixed amount, e.g. `NormalGB.Sample(NormalSampler, screenPosition * 0.01f)`.

The right solution though is to add an additional `float2` texture coordinate input, usually associated with the `TEXCOORD` semantic name.  This should be set in your vertex data to have values between 0 and 1, which are then interpolated in the pixel shader.